# Sort data by row based on a range of values

Tags: r, import-from-csv

My data is:

```
phone   colour  length  weight  rating
100       5      3        3      0
200                       1      4
303       3     30               9
302       2     43        0      2
106      43         
203      23      3        1      7
```

I want my data to look like this:

**Variable A (sort_by_model_100):**

```
phone   colour  length  weight  rating
  100         5      3        3      0
  106        43
```

**Variable B (sort_by_model_200):**

```
phone   colour  length  weight  rating
200       4      20       1      4
203      23      3        1      7
```

**Variable C (sort_by_model_300):**

```
     phone  colour  length  weight  rating
      303     3       30       0      9
      302     2       43       0      2
```

My  **R** code:

```
data <- read.csv(file.choose(),header=TRUE)

sort_by_model_100 <- split (data, data$phone[100:200])
sort_by_model_200 <- split (data, data$phone[200:300])
sort_by_model_300 <- split (data, data$phone[300:400])
```

I get this error and my code doesn't work :

> Warning message:
>       In split.default(x = seq_len(nrow(x)), f = f, drop = drop, ...) :
>         data length is not a multiple of split variable

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `subset`:

```
var_a = subset(data, phone >= 100 & phone < 200)
var_b = subset(data, phone >= 200 & phone < 300)
```

And so on. Maybe you can improve the code to avoid hard-coding the ranges.

Comment: Can subset take multiple inputs? e.g. var_a = subset(data, phone >= 100 & phone < 200 , rating = 0,  ...). Also, why wouldn't I use the or command (|)? e.g.  if phone( 100 | phone < 200) { do this}

Comment: Yes it can, but not in this way. The 'filter' should be on the second argument, like this: `var_a = subset(data, phone >= 100 & phone < 200 & rating == 0)`. You want a range, so the value should be greater than x AND less than x + 100.

Answer (score 0):

With this data

```
data<-data.frame(
    phone=c(100,200,303,302,106,203),
    colour=c(5,NA,3,2,43,23),
    length=c(3,NA,30,43,NA,3),
    weight=c(3,1,NA,0,NA,1),
    rating=c(0,4,9,2,NA,7)
)
```

I'd use cut to create a factor to indicated model class

```
model<-cut(data$phone, breaks=c(100,200,300,400), include.lowest=T, right=F)
```

Then you can use split to create a list of sub-data.frames

```
split(data, model)
```

This is likely to be easier to work with than a bunch of different data.frame variables.

Comment: how will this work if i import a csv file with many rows and columns? Also, google says cut is dangerous D: so when should i use cut? and what does right=F mean?

Comment: Cut is dangerous? I've not heard that. It simply breaks up a continuous range into discrete sets. Read the documentation for `?cut` if you aren't sure what any of the parameters do.

Comment: That's the problem being new to R... everything is new and hard.... is break=r(colour) valid? i.e. beak by row

Comment: `break=r(colour)` doesn't make any sense. The parameter is `breaks`, there is no `r` function and `colour` doesn't exist outside the data.frame. I simply used cut to group all the 100's 200's and 300's together. In what way do you want to group the colours?

Comment: Well, then you wouldn't use cut() because you don't have continuous values. You can just do `split(data, data$colour)` if you wanted a data.frame for each different colour value.